# Hibernate Entity Mapping

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data

Good night everyone,

I want to model a database that has the following entities and their perspective relationships:

[image: uml-relationship]

But everytime I run the Java project to create the model at database, what I create is something like this:

[image: database-articles-table]

There is another way to map this relationship? I'm mapping like that:

Article entity:

```
@Entity
public class Article {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean featured;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String url;

    @Column(name = "image_url", nullable = false)
    private String imageUrl;

    @Column(name = "news_site", nullable = false)
    private String newsSite;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String summary;

    @Column(name = "published_at", nullable = false)
    private String publishedAt;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "launches_id")
    private List<Launches> launches;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "events_id")
    private  List<Events> events;
}
```

Launches entity

```
@Entity
public class Launches {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String provider;
}
```

Events entity:

```
@Entity
public class Events {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String provider;
}
```

And I want to map this JSON, with this same launcher and events appearing in other articles:

```
{
    "id": 4278,
    "title": "GAO warns of more JWST delays",
    "url": "https://spacenews.com/gao-warns-of-more-jwst-delays/",
    "imageUrl": "https://spacenews.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/jwst-assembled.jpg",
    "newsSite": "SpaceNews",
    "summary": "",
    "publishedAt": "2020-01-28T23:25:02.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-05-18T13:46:00.284Z",
    "featured": false,
    "launches": [
        {
            "id": "d0fa4bb2-80ea-4808-af08-7785dde53bf6",
            "provider": "Launch Library 2"
        }
    ],
    "events": []
},
{
    "id": 4304,
    "title": "Government watchdog warns of another JWST launch delay",
    "url": "https://spaceflightnow.com/2020/01/30/government-watchdog-warns-of-another-jwst-launch-delay/",
    "imageUrl": "https://mk0spaceflightnoa02a.kinstacdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/48936479373_2d8a120c8e_k.jpg",
    "newsSite": "Spaceflight Now",
    "summary": "",
    "publishedAt": "2020-01-30T04:08:00.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-05-18T13:46:01.640Z",
    "featured": false,
    "launches": [
        {
            "id": "d0fa4bb2-80ea-4808-af08-7785dde53bf6",
            "provider": "Launch Library 2"
        }
    ],
    "events": []
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to  your diagram, it should be:

```java
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "launches_id")
    private Launches launches;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "events_id")
    private  Events events;
```

...and not `@OneToMany` ;) (Can there be an "Article" (with id=x) having launchers_id=y AND launchers_id=z? No, vice versa!:)

...for the `@OneToMany`, you should find the join columns "on the other side" (of relationship(s)).

---

According to your JSON, it *is* `OneToMany`. But then, we have to draw/expect:

```java
@Entity
class Article {
    //... id, columns, blah
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "article_id")  // Launches "owns the relationship"/column 
    private List<Launches> launches;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "article_id")  // Events...!
    private  List<Events> events;
}
```

Generally, (when you expose your db model via json,) ensure:

- no "circles" (in bi-directional associations). (`@JsonManagedReference, @JsonBackReference, @JsonIgnoreProperties`, ... )
- not to expose data, that you don't want to expose. (`@JsonIgnoreProperties`, ...)

Regarding Hibernate-ManyToOne, please refer to https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Regarding [spring-data-jpa](/questions/tagged/spring-data-jpa), best to:

- [gs-data-jpa](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/)
- [gs-data-rest](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/)
- [spring-boot-ref, data-jpa](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/data.html#data.sql.jpa-and-spring-data)
- [reference-doc, data-jpa](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)
- [reference-doc, data-rest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#reference)

Comment: xerx593 And how would you do if you were to map like in JSON? Being that one launches properties could exist in many articles, but one article could have many launches?

Comment: In that case you need a many-to-many relationship, with the creation of an intermediary table, e.g. `articles_to_launches` which has 2 columns `article_id` and `launch_id`. Under `@ManyToMany` annotation there should be a list of `Launches` for `Articles` and a list of `Articles` for `Launches`. See https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many for guidance.

Comment: Uou that answer was amazing, I'm reading everything right now, thank you so much!!